# How does strnlen() internally work in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm confused how `strnlen` could work in C++ with strings that weren't null terminated, as I 'm not sure how it computes the size.

The `strlen()` implementation is easy:

```
size_t strlen(char *s)
{
    size_t sz;
    while(*s++ != '\0')
    {
        ++sz;
    }
    return sz;
}
```

But how would you implement `strnlen()`?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: The `strnlen(s, maxlen)` function returns `strlen(s)`, if that is less than `maxlen`, or `maxlen` if there is no null byte ('\0') among the first `maxlen` bytes pointed to by `s`.

Comment: yes someone is really frustrated I think ;)

Comment: Do you want strlen or strnlen? These are not the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But how would you implement `strnlen()`?

Like this:

```
size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t max_len)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for(; (i < max_len) && s[i]; ++i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Looks like [gartenriese is still beating you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21536247/1454048) in a little code golf ;)

Comment: You have the test the wrong way around. You shouldn't dereference s[i] beyond 'max_len'. It may not point to anything.

Answer (score 10):

A little shorter than [πάντα ῥεῖ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536128/1454048):

```
size_t strnlen(const char * s, size_t len) {
    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i < len && s[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    return i;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To clarify for future readers and possible downvoters, when I wrote this answer, my code was in fact shorter. Now it's not anymore, because the other post was edited. I don't think that this should be a reason to downvote me.

Comment: May be because you could even omit the `{}` (I didn't downvote)

Comment: lol, two seconds after deleting the curly brackets, I got 2 upvotes. EDIT: And now it's down again, it's like a rollercoaster. Maybe I shouldn't answer in the future if there are already sufficient answers.

Comment: @admdrew At least it refers to my answer, which was given a few minutes faster (being also correct at this time). You can **always** optimize later, as soon you've got everything right ;) ...

Comment: @gartenriese Sorry! Again, I didn't downvote (just retracted my upvote after admdrew's edit).

Comment: Well, to make things clear and to end this "race", I gave you an upvote, so we can go on with our lives. ;-)

Comment: Well, you guys still need to curry favors with [Joseph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3246054/joseph) in an attempt to win his accept vote.

Comment: After the serial downvotes, I have a feeling that he won't accept any of the answers ...

Comment: @gartenriese At the moment it looks the [upvotes outweigh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3246054/joseph?tab=reputation) ...

Comment: Oh, sorry then, I am retracting my probably false accusation. :-)

Comment: if you're aiming at shortness, why use `s[i] != '\0'` when `s[i]` would suffice? (Just curious, not voting either way here)

Comment: @rici: I wasn't aiming at code golf shortness in particular. The other post had two temporaries, so I thought I could give an answer that required only one. Also, I didn't even know that s[i] was sufficient up until now, thanks for that! :-)

Comment: If you want to do code golf, [we have a site for that](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).  This answer is just a duplicate and adds nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`strnlen == min(n, strlen)`

e.g. instead of

```
while(*s++ != '\0')
```

use

```
for(int i = 0; i < n && *s++ != '\0'; i++)
```

or any equivalent.

In the future, [feel free to read the source yourself](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-80/bash/lib/sh/strnlen.c), which I just found by googling "strnlen source code."

Answer (score 2):

Your code is invalid because variable sz was not initialized

```
size_t sz;
```

I think it is simply a typo.

Also the parameter should be defined as `const char *s`

`strnlen` is not a C++ standard function. It is defined only in C. it could be defined the following way

```
size_t strnlen( const char *s, size_t n )
{
   size_t i = 0;

   while ( i < n && s[i] ) ++i;

   return i;
}
```

In C++ it could be declared having a default argument

```
size_t strnlen( const char *s, size_t n = -1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

> But how would you implement strnlen?

You really don't need to in C++, just use `std::find` like so.

```
auto length = std::find(s, s + max_len, 0) - s;
```

Or if you want to wrap it up in a template function so it also works with more than just single byte characters.

```
template<type Type>
size_t strnlen(const Type* s, size_t max_len)
{
    return std::find(s, s + max_len, 0) - s;
}
```